# PHP Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, terminal, laravel-5.3

I have object a problem looping data collection,

seem's like this below

> collect($extracts->each(function($object, $okey){
>       print_r($okey);
>       print_r($object); });

the result is like this:

> $object( [items:protected] => Array
>
> ```
>     (
>         [PAL175MW1_Protelindo Besusu ManggisMW1] => 29273552197058179
>         [PAL175MW1_Protelindo Besusu ManggisMW2] => 29273552197058180
>         [PAL175MW1_Protelindo Besusu ManggisMW3] => 29273552197058181
>         [PAL175MX1_Protelindo Besusu ManggisMX1] => 29273552197058182
>    ) )
> ```
>
> how can I get value like this->(29273552197058179,29273552197058180)
>   from the $object

Comment: Did you try `implode` like this `implode(",", $object)` ?

Comment: i try implode and cannot work, because i want get id by name.... i want try $objects->get($okey)->id